# How to get azure metrics data from azure using REST API

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-monitoring

I wanted to fetch the azure appservice metrics data from azure and insert it into grphite DB for further analysis. Is there an API's how can I fetch the metrics data from azure?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Azure Monitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metrics/list) Rest API

```
GET https://management.azure.com/{resourceUri}/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?api-version=2018-01-01
```

Comment: what is resourceUri and how to get acccess token?

Comment: click on the link, it has a try it option